# arduino-esp32 do OTA via BLE

Tags: arduino, esp32

Anyone know how to do arduino-esp32 OTA via BLE. I wanna use tablet to update ESP32. Tablet download firmware and transfer to ESP32, and ESP32 save it in to partition and reboot.

Comment: this applies https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/57940/gprs-based-ota-to-the-nodemcu/57942#57942

Comment: This is totally different question. In my case. I don’t have gprs. ESP32 not able to connect to internet directly.

Comment: Transport the bin file over Bluetooth and then use the Update singleton object. It is declared in Update.h. Example is ArduinoOTAClass::_runUpdate() in ArduinoOTA.cpp or ESP8266HTTPUpdate::runUpdate() in ESP8266httpUpdate.cpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after some research, this is what I am looking for.

https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/Update/examples

We can use "SD_Update" example to do BLE OTA. tablet transfer bin file to ESP32 and save it into SPIFFS as a bin file. after the data transfer. Follow SD_Update to start OTA