# Arduino ESP32 receive file over BLE (for OTA update)

Tags: xamarin.forms, arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I want to send a file (bin) from my Xamarin Forms (C#) iOS App over BLE (https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le) to my ESP32 (Arduino). That file would be a bin file for updating. I found already a solution on how to update the ESP32 out of spiffs ([arduino-esp32 do OTA via BLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367523/arduino-esp32-do-ota-via-ble)) but does anyone know how I can receive the file with the ESP32 and save it into spiffs?

(The BLE  connection app to esp32 is already fully working, I can send texts, but I don't know how to send files)

Best regards
nflug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to send the file content as individual bytes and save it to SPIFFS

You can create and write to a binary file using the function below (Arduino code)

```
void writeBinary(fs::FS &fs, const char * path, uint8_t *dat, int len) {

  //Serial.printf("Write binary file %s\r\n", path);

  File file = fs.open(path, FILE_APPEND);

  if (!file) {
    Serial.println("- failed to open file for writing");
    return;
  }
  file.write(dat, len);
  file.close();
}
```

Check out the usage here [ESP32_BLE_OTA_Arduino](https://github.com/fbiego/ESP32_BLE_OTA_Arduino).

I have also created an android app to upload the file [ESP32_BLE_OTA_Android](https://github.com/fbiego/ESP32_BLE_OTA_Android)